# Navigation properties in EF41 with code first, without having a foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to create/map navigation properties in EF41 with code first, without having a foreign key?
In my case i need it for historization:

```
public class Person
{
 public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
 public virtual string Name { get; set; }
 public virtual IList<PersonHist> History { get; set; }
}

public class PersonHist
{
 public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
 public virtual Guid PersonID { get; set; }
 public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Imagine: A Person was changed several time, so in Person is one entry and in PersonHist are N historical entries. Now i delete the Person, so Person should not have this Person and PersonHist has now one entry more. But this is not possible with a foreign key...
(I don't want a deleted Flag/Column in Person!, but i want a navigation property from Person to PersonHist...)

Answer (score 0):

Logic behind navigation properties is based on foreign keys. So if you want to map it and use it as a navigation property you must have foreign key in `PersonHist`. You can make the key nullable but you will have to correctly use it:

- Modify mapping to remove cascade delete used by default
- Set null to all related `PersonHist` before deleting the `Person` or implement custom database initializer and replace referential constraint with `ON DELETE SET NULL`

If you don't want foreign key don't use it as a navigation property and use separate query to get historical records for person - but it will still require some column pointing to original `Person` record.